# to store unsorted key value pair

Tags: c++, stl

Is there any container available in C++ STL to store unsorted key value pair with duplicate keys?

I was thinking *std::unordered_multimap* container will help me in this case but the elements with equivalent keys are grouped together in this.

Comment: `std::vector<std::pair<key, value>>`?

Comment: why you need stl then...simply use a 2d array :p

Comment: thanks @user657267. I didnt think of this.

Comment: @RajeevSingh. I need to insert data dynamically and I dont want to do any malloc and realloc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to look at [sequence containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/SequenceContainer). Basically you can store *std::pair< key, value >* at some sequence container.

If you just need to store key-value pairs and sometimes add new key-value pair at the end of the container then *std::vector* is enough. If you additionally want to insert elements in the beginning of the container then look at *std::deque*. And so on...

So the best strategy is to analyze your constraints and choose the appropriate sequence container.